# Bing C# Image Search API DataServiceQueryException

Tags: c#, bing-api

I've been attempting to use the Bing Image Search API in C#. It worked fine up until recently for no apparent reason: I am now getting a "DataServiceQueryException" when I execute the actual request. Here's the relevant code:

```
var query = searchBox.Text;
const string rootUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search";
var bingContainer = new BingSearchContainer(new Uri(rootUrl));

const string market = "en-us";

bingContainer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(AccountKey, AccountKey);

var imageQuery = bingContainer.Image(query, null, market, null, null, null, null);
imageQuery = imageQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);

var temp = imageQuery.Execute();
```

The exception is being thrown on the last line (imageQuery.Execute()). If any more details are necessary, I'd be glad to provide them.

Comment: Please try it again, after you have removed the `imageQuery = ` in your second last line before `imageQuery.AddQueryOption("$top", 10);`..

Comment: It doesn't work, and removing the whole line also doesn't work (same error). I'll make the change anyways, just because I find it cleaner.

Comment: Also, if it helps, doing the almost exact same code using "bingContainer.Web" works fine (and changing any other relevant code/types), but obviously returns web searches instead of image searches.

Comment: Just looked into it more, I seem to be getting a 404 error somehow: I'll check back once I have more information.

Comment: I have no idea how, but I just redid the code and it seems to spontaneously work now. I'll confirm this when I try to work back to where I was and see if the error appears again.